# Is it possible to change ShowDurationPicker colors in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to change duration pickers color theme but the package does not allow me to change.
In other timer pickers like showTimePickers the widget containes a builder where you can add a theme to it but in this one there is no builder.
I am currently using this package [pub.dev link](https://pub.dev/packages/duration_picker)

I tried to wrap it with a theme but that didn't help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put your ThemeData in MaterialApp like this, you can easily change colors in showDurationPicker:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:duration_picker/duration_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Duration Picker Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
          primary: Colors.red,
          secondary: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Test')),
      body: Container(),
      floatingActionButton: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            var resultingDuration = await showDurationPicker(
              context: context,
              initialTime: const Duration(minutes: 20),
            );

            if (!mounted) return;
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text('Choose duration: $resultingDuration')));
          },
          tooltip: 'Popup Duration Picker',
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This method work only on the text and buttons but does not work on the background !

Comment: I tried setting ColorScheme.dark but I couldn't control the color is there a way to set it to a specific color ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I found the solution there is a decoration parameter for the showDuration widget where you can set BoxDecoration but thanks for helping with the other colors 